# Generating a value in a step function based on a variable

Tags: optimization, gurobi, pyomo

Im creating an optimization model using gurobi and have some trouble with one of my constraints. The constraint is used to establish the quantity and is based on supply and demand curves. The supply curves cause the problems as it is a step curve. As seen in the code, the problem is when im writing the def MC section.

```
Demand_Curve1_const = 250
Demand_Curve1_slope = -0.025
MC_water = 0
MC_gas = 80
MC_coal = 100
CAP_water = 5000
CAP_gas = 2500
CAP_coal = 2000

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()


model.Const_P1 = pyo.Param(initialize = Demand_Curve1_const)

model.slope_P1 = pyo.Param(initialize = Demand_Curve1_slope)

model.MCW = pyo.Param(initialize = MC_water)
model.MCG = pyo.Param(initialize = MC_gas)
model.MCC = pyo.Param(initialize = MC_coal) 

model.CW = pyo.Param(initialize = CAP_water)
model.CG = pyo.Param(initialize = CAP_gas)
model.CC = pyo.Param(initialize = CAP_coal)

model.qw = pyo.Var(within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.qg = pyo.Var(within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.qc = pyo.Var(within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)
model.d = pyo.Var(within = pyo.NonNegativeReals)

def MC():
    if model.d <=5000:
        return model.MCW
    if model.d >= 5000 and model.d <= 7500:
        return model.MCG
    if model.d >= 7500 :
        return model.MCC

def Objective(model):
    return(model.Const_P1*model.d + model.slope_P1*model.d*model.d - (model.MCW*model.qw + model.MCG*model.qg + model.MCC*model.qc))
model.OBJ = pyo.Objective(rule = Objective, sense = pyo.maximize)


def P1inflow(model):
    return(MC == model.Const_P1+model.slope_P1*model.d*2)
model.C1 = pyo.Constraint(rule = P1inflow)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `MC` as stated would make the model nonlinear, and in a rather nasty way (discontinuous).

Piecewise linear functions are often modeled through binary variables or SOS2 sets (Special Ordered Sets of type 2). As you are using Pyomo, you can also use a tool that can generate MIP formulations automatically for you. See `help(Piecewise)`.

An example that fits your description is [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/pyomo/piecewise/step.py).